# Plotting glm in R throws error regarding row counts in x and y

Tags: r, plot, glm, predict

I'm trying to plot a glm in R, my current code is as follows, but I keep getting the error as shown:

Code:

```
RAVE_CYC_PR3_reg <- glm(RAVE_CYC_PR3$`BVAS/WG Score` ~ RAVE_CYC_PR3$Days,
                        family=poisson())
summary(RAVE_CYC_PR3_reg)
plot(RAVE_CYC_PR3$Days, RAVE_CYC_PR3$`BVAS/WG Score`)
plot(x=seq(0,365,1), predict(RAVE_CYC_PR3_reg, 
                             newdata = data.frame(days=seq(0,365,1)),
                             type = "response"))
```

Error:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
>     'x' and 'y' lengths differ
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   'newdata' had 366 rows but variables found have 393 rows

My intention is to plot both the raw data that I have as well as the predicted values from the glm to visualize how well the model fits the data.

Thank you all for any input.

Comment: Have you tried extending your 'newdata'? instead of `data.frame(days=seq(0,365,1))`, have you tried `data.frame(days=seq(0,392,1))`? Your warning message is telling you that x and y lengths differ.

Comment: Sort of, I would have to increase x as the output of predict is too large, or shorten the data frame. While this works in terms of plotting, I'd rather understand the root cause, since with the current situation I'm not sure if the x-y coordinates are aligned appropriately